# How to enable Audit Trail on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-administration

I am currently using PostgreSQL 9.1. I want to enable pg Audit Trail.

Can someone please help me with that as I am totally new on this thing.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported Postgres version?

Comment: Is the supported version 9.5 and 9.6 . If yes then how can i install pgAudit for that. --Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no audit functionality available by default in the opensource postgresql database. You can check out `edb_audit` from Enterprisedb postgres for creating audit logs.

Or check out the [pgAudit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit) extension for the opensource version.

Comment: Will this pgAudit Extension provide me with the detailed report e.g. which user at what date and time made changes to that particular table.

Comment: You can have session level or object level audit with this. It will log the Statement, session id, Statement type and execution time.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But my requirement is wherein i want to capture all the details including the username or user id who made changes to a table . E.g. If someone inserts a junk column and i want to find out the user who performed this activity. How can i do this in postgresql database.

Comment: Username is also logged in the audit logs. You can get more details by querying pg_stat_activity view with session id. You can refer [this](https://www.openscg.com/2016/10/auditing-database-changes-using-pgaudit/) page for info on how to setup/test pgaudit in database.

Comment: Thank You on that.When does pgaudit.log file gets created ? Post setting the shared_preload_libraries='pgaudit'; or before that when we set up Postgres 9.6